# What exactly are out_of_sync Puppet Resources?

Tags: puppet

In the puppet_run_summary.yaml reports one of the categories for resources is out_of_sync. What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "out of sync" resource is one where the puppet agent detects that a change is needed and acts on it - so, for example, a file where the content or permissions doesn't match, or a service in the wrong state.

This can differ from "changed" resources count for a run, in that the "changed" count is for successful changes, while the "out of sync" count will also include resources that were detected as out of sync but not successfully changed - either those that didn't successfully sync ("failed") or that didn't attempt to sync due to `--noop` ("pending").

Comment: Spot-on explanation. Looks even prettier in Puppet Dashboard.